# SQL select default value when there is no such value

Tags: mysql, left-join, coalesce

I have following tables in DB.

**ACCOUNT** TABLE

```
  User_id|  first_name |  last_name |   age   |        
  _______|_____________|____________|_________|
     1   |    LeBron   |   James    |    28   |
     2   |    Kobe     |   Bryent   |    29   |
     3   |    Kevin    |   Durant   |    30   |
     4   |    Jim      |   Jones    |    31   |
     5   |    Paul     |   Pierce   |    32   |
     6   |    Jeremy   |   Lin      |    33   |
```

**USER_BOOKMARK** TABLE

```
  User_id|  Bookmarked_user_id
  _______|____________________
     1   |     2        
     1   |     3      
     1   |     4
     2   |     1        
     2   |     4     
     3   |     1
     5   |     6
```

I want to select user's information from **ACCOUNT** table and also whether that person is in my **Bookmark list**

**ex)** Lebron James wants to know Jeremy Lin's information and whether Jeremy is in he's bookmark lists.

**Desired results** =>

```
  User_id|  first_name |  last_name |   age   | isBookmarked |       
  _______|_____________|____________|_________|______________|      
     6   |    Jeremy   |     Lin    |    33   |      0       |  =>0 means no.

  *It must return only one row.
  *If user is on my bookmark list, value of isBookmarked is my user_id.
```

What I tried =>

```
 SELECT ACCOUNT.user_id, ACCOUNT.firstname, ACCOUNT.lastname, coalesce(User_Bookmark.user_id, 0) as isBookmarked
 FROM Account LEFT OUTER JOIN User_Bookmark ON Account.user_id = User_Bookmark.Bookmarked_user_id
 WHERE Account.user_id=6 AND User_Bookmark.user_id=1
```

But this query returns zero rows... since I'm not an expert on sql, I assume that I'm missing something. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `User_Bookmark.user_id = 1` test is filtering out the non-matching rows, because that column will be `NULL` when there's no match. When doing a `LEFT JOIN`, you have to put conditions on the second table into the `ON` clause rather than `WHEN`.

```
SELECT ACCOUNT.user_id, ACCOUNT.firstname, ACCOUNT.lastname, coalesce(User_Bookmark.user_id, 0) as isBookmarked
FROM Account 
LEFT OUTER JOIN User_Bookmark 
    ON Account.user_id = User_Bookmark.Bookmarked_user_id AND User_Bookmark.user_id=1
 WHERE Account.user_id=6
```

Comment: Thanks for super fast and perfect answer!